# IE7 context menu options for javascript links

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

In IE8, Safari, Chrome and Firefox if I right-click on the link the new tab and new window options are disabled.  Right-clicking the link in IE7 still has these two options enabled.  Is there any way to disabled these options in IE7 for javascript links?

Sample Code:

```
<html>
<body>
<a href="javascript: alert('Hello');">Javascript link</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This does not have anything to do with the HTML, but the browser. I am 99.9% sure you can't change it, it's hardcoded in IE7 by Microsoft. Submit a bug to Microsoft, but they'll probably say "We no longer support IE7, nor do we give a crap about your problems." (Maybe not exactly like that :) ).

So, this is not a programming question, it's a software question, hence why you got downvoted (I didn't do it, but that's my assumption).